# can i get a realtime value>

Tags: pine-script, real-time

i have a question..

I want to short when the high point of the one-hour bar is updated, and long when the low point of the one-hour bar is updated.

i'm trying to get the current price with funtion that

```
request.sequrity(syminfo.ticker, "1", close)
```

when it applied to a indicator, it updates in real time, but when using stategy it doesn't update according to the real time price. Is there a way to get the real-time price in ticks?

get realtime value from tradingview

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `calc_on_every_tick` argument of your `strategy()` to `true`.

> ***calc_on_every_tick (const bool)*** Specifies whether the strategy should
> be recalculated on each realtime tick. If true, when the strategy is
> running on a realtime bar, it will recalculate on each chart update.
> If false, the strategy only calculates when the realtime bar closes.
> The argument used does not affect strategy calculation on historical
> data. This setting can also be changed in the strategy's
> "Settings/Properties" tab. Optional. The default is false.

Comment: thank you very much, issue has been cleared. you save me